# Save python plistlib data

Tags: python

how do I save the output I get for this program(as a variable), instead of it being printed?

```
import plistlib, time
import plistlib as pl
p=pl.readPlist("Restore.plist")
print p["ProductType"]#I want this to be outputted as a variable, such as 'x' instead of   python printing it.
print p["ProductVersion"]
print p["ProductBuildVersion"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
outputfile = open('output.plist', 'w')
outputfile.write(p["ProductVersion"])
outputfile.close()
```

Comment: precisely!!! THX. I totally forgot I could do it like this too.. :) Hopefully I can get my program to work now.

Answer (score 0):

It's already a variable. Namely, it's part of the variable p. If you want to assign it to another variable use the `=` sign like on line 3 of your code.